# Need to count rows from two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to count the number of times [Tracking id] & [Tracking ID1] appear in a table.

[image]

The result should look like this.

[image]

This works great when I use a group by function.

```
select [Group], datename(month,[date]) as Month, count([Tracking ID]) + count([Tracking ID1]) as [Number of Record]
from   [Table]
group by    
    [Group],
    datename(month,[date])
```

I need to use a pivot function. How do I modify the code below to get the desired results

```
select * 
from 
    (
select  
    [Group], datename(month,[date]) as Month, (count([Tracking ID])over () + count([Tracking ID1]) over () ) as [Number of Record]
From    
    [Table]
) sourcetbl
pivot
    (count([Number of Record])  
for [Month] in ([June], [July])
) as pivotTable;
```

Currently, my query returns 2 instead of 4.

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work based on the information provided:

```
SELECT
    [Group],
    ISNULL([June], 0) AS [June],
    ISNULL([July], 0) AS [July]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        [Group],
        DATENAME(MONTH, [Date]) AS [Date],
        COUNT(Tracking_ID) + COUNT(Tracking_ID1) AS NumberOfRecords
    FROM [Table]
    GROUP BY [Group], [Date]
) AS D
PIVOT
(
    MAX(NumberOfRecords)
    FOR [Date] IN 
    (
        [June],
        [July]
    )
) AS PIV
```

It seems the OVER() parts in your query were causing the COUNT functions to not behave as aggregate functions, thus your query works without a GROUP BY where in this case it needs to have a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select [Group],
       sum(case when month([date]) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as jun,
       sum(case when month([date]) = 7 then 1 else 0 end) as jul
from  [Table]
group by [Group];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it wont work. I need count the numbe of  times [Tracking id] & [Tracking ID1] appear. You example will return 2 instead of.

Comment: @user716255 . . . Are they ever `NULL`?

Comment: No, are no nulls.

Comment: @user716255 . . . Then the counts are the same and the same as the `sum()` in this answer.

Comment: I am not getting the desired results. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Based on your sample results, you just need to multiply the `sum()` by 2.